# Count likes on Facebook post

Tags: php, facebook, post, facebook-like

I am new to facebook programming and trying to read number of likes on certain posts.

```
"data": [
{
  "likes": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "xxx", 
        "id": "10005270697255"
      }
    ], 
    "count": 1
  }, 
  "id": "100005270197255_103639323125074", 
  "created_time": "2013-02-19T17:13:25+0000"
},
```

How could i get number from "count"? :)

Answer (score 0):

How about `data['likes']['count']`

Comment: I got id like this:     $idStatus = idx($status, 'id'); How can i use your code?

Comment: it isnt? :) i am trying to get id and number of likes... i use this sentence: $statusi = idx($facebook->api('/me/posts?fields=likes,id'), 'data', array());

Comment: just realized that i am also not going through all the post - guess because of access problem... pfff

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the whole data structure, but once you have `data`, it should be:

```
data[0].likes.count
```